# Is there a way to pivot_wider certain values and not others from a specific column?

Tags: r

what I have:

> Symbol  Date  Value

> A.     07/20    10
>
> A.     09/20.  12
>
> B.     07/20.  15
>
> B.     08/20.  19
>
> VFINX.  07/20.  22
>
> VFINX   08/20.  20

what I need:

> Symbol  Date  Value. VFINX

> A.     07/20   10.   22
>
> A.     09/20.  12.  20
>
> B.     07/20.  15.  22
>
> B.     08/20.  19.  20

libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
library(purrr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(psych)
library(broom)
library(ustyc)
library(quantmod)
```

1. Here I've downloaded some stock data, and am trying to set it up for a regression analysis using the broom package. I've been able to do this one way, but want to see if I can't do it another.
2. Here is the first way.

'''

```
tickers <- c("A",
             "AAL",
             "AAP",
             "AAPL",
             "ADI",
             "ABBV",
             "ABC",
             "VFINX")
 returns <- tickers %>%
  tq_get( from = "2017-01-01", to ="2019-12-01", get="stock.prices") %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(adjusted, periodReturn, period = "monthly") %>%
  mutate(RF = .02/12,
         Excess_Return = (monthly.returns-RF)*100)

View(returns)


finalized <- returns %>% 
  select(symbol, date, Excess_Return) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = symbol, values_from = Excess_Return)

View(finalized)


steps <- finalized[-1] %>%
  select(everything()) %>%
  gather(Var, Val, -VFINX) %>% #here we are just pivot_longer-ing the data besides the VFINX and just creating two columns (Var, and Val)
  nest(data= c(Val, VFINX)) %>% #nesting the value (the return for each month of the stock) and the VFINX return for that same month
  mutate(
    model = map(data, ~lm(Val~VFINX, data= .)), #here we're applying the same formula to each of the nested data
    tidied = map(model, tidy) # here we are tidying the data for each of the nested here
  ) %>%
  unnest(tidied)
)
```

'''

3. IDEALLY what I want is to skip having to pivot_wider everything and the VFINX first and then pivot back everything BESIDES the VFINX. I instead want to pivot JUST the values where it is the VFINX in the symbols column. Shouldn't it repeat the sequence for each stock if I do something like this? Here I am specifying the certain symbol I want [which(returns2$symbol == VFINX)]. Instead I am getting this error

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `VFINX`, `VFINX`, `VFINX`, `VFINX`, `VFINX`, etc. don't exist.

'''

```
 returns2 <- tickers %>%
      tq_get( from = "2017-01-01", to ="2019-12-01", get="stock.prices") %>%
      group_by(symbol) %>%
      tq_transmute(adjusted, periodReturn, period = "monthly") %>%
      mutate(RF = .02/12,
             Excess_Return = (monthly.returns-RF)*100)
    View(returns2)
    
    returns2<- returns2 %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = returns2$symbol[which(returns2$symbol=="VFINX")], values_from=Excess_Return)
      
'''
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, including data to work with.  (`dput` output is best.)  If this is really just a question about `pivot_wider`, you may not need all of the specific processing steps you've posted here.  Consider whether it's possible to demonstrate the core operation you'd like to perform with `pivot_wider` (or without it), and create a simple, toy data set that shows a starting point and then an expected outcome. That will make the problem much easier to evaluate. At minimum, please edit your post to include the libraries you're using and enough data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @andrew_reece the data is created when the code runs, and the format it comes out from after dput is not ideal. What is there is reproducible, all that's required is for one to input the code and then run it.

Comment: Adding a definition for `tickers` does make it reproducible, thanks for the edit.  You still might consider distilling your question down to a simple example that isolates the problem - it's easier to get help faster that way.  And it makes it easier for others who land on your question in the future to understand what the central issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, this gets you from "what i have" to "what i need":

```r
returns %>% 
  select(symbol, date, Excess_Return) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(vfinx = Excess_Return[symbol == "VFINX"]) %>% 
  ungroup

# A tibble: 280 x 4
   symbol date       Excess_Return   vfinx
   <chr>  <date>             <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A      2017-01-31         5.17   0.856 
 2 A      2017-02-28         4.59   3.80  
 3 A      2017-03-31         3.15  -0.0721
 4 A      2017-04-28         3.96   0.851 
 5 A      2017-05-31         9.44   1.23  
 6 A      2017-06-30        -1.65   0.445 
 7 A      2017-07-31         0.643  1.88  
 8 A      2017-08-31         8.08   0.127 
 9 A      2017-09-29        -0.970  1.89  
10 A      2017-10-31         6.02   2.15
```

You can fit the regressions by `symbol` (leaving out `symbol == 'VFINX'`) like this:

```r
returns %>% 
  select(symbol, date, Excess_Return) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(vfinx = Excess_Return[symbol == "VFINX"]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(symbol != "VFINX") %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  summarise(fit = list(lm(Excess_Return ~ vfinx, data = .) %>% tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(fit)
```

Output

```r
# A tibble: 14 x 6
   symbol term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
   <chr>  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 A      (Intercept)   -0.234     0.467    -0.501 6.17e- 1
 2 A      vfinx          1.24      0.129     9.63  8.51e-19
 3 AAL    (Intercept)   -0.234     0.467    -0.501 6.17e- 1
 4 AAL    vfinx          1.24      0.129     9.63  8.51e-19
 5 AAP    (Intercept)   -0.234     0.467    -0.501 6.17e- 1
 6 AAP    vfinx          1.24      0.129     9.63  8.51e-19
 7 AAPL   (Intercept)   -0.234     0.467    -0.501 6.17e- 1
 8 AAPL   vfinx          1.24      0.129     9.63  8.51e-19
 9 ABBV   (Intercept)   -0.234     0.467    -0.501 6.17e- 1
10 ABBV   vfinx          1.24      0.129     9.63  8.51e-19
11 ABC    (Intercept)   -0.234     0.467    -0.501 6.17e- 1
12 ABC    vfinx          1.24      0.129     9.63  8.51e-19
13 ADI    (Intercept)   -0.234     0.467    -0.501 6.17e- 1
14 ADI    vfinx          1.24      0.129     9.63  8.51e-19
```

Comment: Perfect, the only thing I needed was this part mutate (vfinx = Excess_Return[symbol == "VFINX"]) %>% 
  ungroup

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.  If this answer best resolved your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the relevant `Excess_Return` value for `'VFINX'` and add it as new column for each `symbol`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

returns2 %>%
  filter(symbol == 'VFINX') %>%
  pull(Excess_Return) -> val
  
returns2 %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  mutate(VFINX_col = val)
```

Comment: The problem with that is I need it to be there for each and every stock next to it if that makes sense. I have seven stocks, I need that VFINX list to be a column for as many times as there are stocks.... Filtering only gives me the pivoting of VFINX. I need the original data with the pivoted VFINX next to it

Comment: Hmm....isn't that what you have in `finalized` ? Maybe I am misunderstanding, can you show first few rows of your expected output?

Comment: Do you need to add `%>% full_join(returns2)` to above output so that you get your original data.

Comment: Just added what I am trying to get to. In that first bit of code I created, I pivoted ALL of the data from long to wide, and then when I go through my regression line I'm gathering (pivoting wider) everything BESIDES the VFINX. What I'm trying to do in step three is cut out that middle part. Can't I pivot wider JUST the VFINX and have it replicated down numerous times as I've demonstrated in the example. Why does pivot longer create it multiple times but not pivot wider?

Comment: Check if the updated answer is what you want @kingatlas .

Comment: So simple, sorry about this